# Advanced Filter on PowerQuery

Tags: powerquery

**Question**

I am trying to filter some excel data I have on PowerQuery but am really struggling to figure out the best way to do this. On Excel I would usually do this using an Advanced Filter but I don't believe Power Query has the same functionality.

I would like to filter across a number of columns, using an OR condition for a:

1. a range of values in some columns; and
2. a range of 'wild card' searches in other columns

**Example**

As an example if my dataset is as below

| Name | Function | Sub-Function | Position | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Andy | Sales | Omni-Channel | Sales Manager | Brazil |
| Bob | Marketing | eCommerce | Web Design | Argentina |
| Rakesh | HR | Business Partnering | HRBP | Italy |
| Tom | Finance | Reporting | Finance Manager | UK |
| Chris | Sales | Trade Marketing | Sales support | US |
| Raj | Legal | Legal | Para-legal | Brazil |

I might want to filter for anyone meeting the following criteria;

- working in the sales function OR
- working in the Trade Marketing or Omni-Channel sub-function OR
- has the words 'Manager' or 'Sales' in their Position title OR
- is based in Brazil

The desired output would then be

| Name | Function | Sub-Function | Position | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Andy | Sales | Omni-Channel | Sales Manager | Brazil |
| Tom | Finance | Reporting | Finance Manager | UK |
| Chris | Sales | Trade Marketing | Sales support | US |
| Raj | Legal | Legal | Para-legal | Brazil |

**My current approach**

My approach was to create a table which had all my criteria (not including the 'wild card' searches), upload to PowerQuery, create multiple lists from this table (called for example Filter1, Filter2 etc..). Then using the following formula against my main dataset

= Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows1", each (List.Contains(Filter1,[Function]) = true) or (List.Contains(Filter2,[Sub-Function]) = true) or (List.Contains(Filter3,[Country]) = true) or Text.Contains([Position], "Manager") or Text.Contains([Position], "Sales"))

**Issues**

- The formula above works for really small data sets however not on my 80,000 line data set, or rather it does not work within a reasonable time frame
- I have a long list of 'wild card' searches which apply to three columns so typing in the Text.Contain(...... etc.. formula multiple times into the formula seems very inefficient, is prone to mistakes and is not dynamic in any way.

I'm sure there must be a better way to do this but I have not found many helpful discussions or tutorials on this online so am reaching out to the community.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the part of the problem the query is slow as with your current approach, filtering is evaluating filtering conditions separately before it could filter. Power bi is capable of handling filter on multiple columns in a single filter, like following

```
Table.SelectRows(
    #"Changed Type1", 
    each ([Function] = "Sales")
      or ([#"Sub-Function"] = "Trade Marketing" or [#"Sub-Function"] = "Omni-Channel")
      or (
        Text.Contains([Position], "Manager")
          or Text.Contains([Position], "Sales")
          or ([Country] = "Brazil")
      )
  )
```

[image: Filtering on multiple columns]

Comment: Unfortunately I have too many criteria to make this option viable, think 400 OR conditions, but thank you for your answer